# comparing vector value with a integer

Tags: c++, vector

Check the vector of integers for the particular value
== "comparison" operator is available that work for vector==vector 
can we do this 
vector[i]==value
i have tried this

```
    if(SolutionMatrix[i]==0)
```

here SolutionMatrix is integer type vector

```
    vector<int> SolutionMatrix;
```

can anybody help me regrading this.
 code is

```
for(int index=0;index<SolutionMatrix.size();i++)
  {

        vector<int> b(SolutionMatrix[i].size());
        vector<int> c(SolutionMatrix[i].size());
        int j,k;
        j=k=0;

            for(i=0;i<SolutionMatrix[i].size();i++)
            {

                    if(SolutionMatrix[i]==0)
                    {
                         b[j++]=i;

                    }               
                    else
                    {

                        c[k++]=i;
                    }

            }
            b.resize(j);
            c.resize(k);
}
```

Comment: You might be looking for `std::find`. I can't tell, though.

Comment: but its givig the error ......... Error is                                binary '==' : 'class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: @Khan Show the exact _relevant_ code

Comment: i have added the code @pow u can see

Comment: @Khan `SolutionMatrix` is not vector of vector, so `SolutionMatrix[i].size()` is wrong

Comment: @Khan Is it a typo that instead of index++ there is i++ in statement for(int index=0;index<SolutionMatrix.size();i++)
  {

Comment: @pow  i m try to do this for one row vector of vectors until the  whole vector of vectors is done

Answer (score 1):

If you need to determine whether there is a vector element that is equal to a given value then you can use either standard algorithm `std::find` or `std::any_of`

For example

```
if ( std::find( SolutionMatrix.begin(), SolutionMatrix.end(), 0 ) != SolutionMatrix.end() )
{
   std::cout << "0 is found" << std::endl;
}
```

or you can use the same range based for statement. For example

bool found = false;

```
for ( int x : SolutionMatrix )
{
   if ( found = x == 0 ) break;
}

if ( found ) 
{
   std::cout << "0 is found" << std::endl;
}
```

EDIT: As for your code that appeared after my answer then I do not see any sense in it. Within the outer loop you defined local vectors b and c that will be destroyed and created anew in each iteration.

You could use the same range based for statement.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 5 };

    std::vector<int> b;
    b.reserve( a.size() / 2 );
    std::vector<int> c;
    c.reserve( a.size() / 2 );

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( int x : a )
    {
        if( x == 0 )
        {
            b.push_back( i );
        }
        else
        {
            c.push_back( i );
        }

        ++i;
    }

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : b ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : c ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 0 2 0 0 4 5 
1 3 4 
0 2 5 6
```

Comment: can you explain this line for me  for ( int x : SolutionMatrix )

Comment: which IDE are You using2

Comment: giving error in for ( int x : a ) for ( int x : b ) for ( int x : c )

Comment: @Khan  I used the online compiler for C++ 11 at www.ideone.com

Comment: @Khan  instead of the range based for statement you can use an ordinary loop.

Comment: error is error C2059: syntax error : ':' and highlights the lines i mentioned in above comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61179/discussion-between-khan-and-vlad-from-moscow).